# Juniors backstabbed me

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, politics, junior, seniority

Currently in my new office, there are two juniors under me that both have 1 year of experience. In all my career of 4+ years, I have always helped my juniors. In the case of these two juniors, I have always helped them whenever I could. Even when they did mistakes, I never shouted. Just talked calmly and made them understand their mistakes and whenever I had the time, fixed the mistakes myself.

The worst event happened when one of the juniors just wasn't doing what I told him to do. I told him to do a task and then move on to the next one. But he skipped the "boring" task and started doing the "interesting" task first. After I told him not to do it multiple times, he got his friend, the second junior, and in front of everyone, spouted lies after lies to my senior, like how I don't help them at all.

My seniors saw through their lies. But the reason I am writing this question is how fake people can be? They were taking and laughing with me and just when I thought I could trust them, they did this. Whom to trust when these so "good" actors are in this world? Are really all people like this and do I really need to stop being "innocent" and lie and don't help juniors. Because I don't know what I should do.

Comment: Your senior saw straight through the lies, continue doing your job and help them when you can. Just be wary now that you know.

Comment: I'm not sure we can really answer to that. You need to address a specific goal that we can answer in the workplace. Your current goal seems like "how to detect such people ?" We can't answer that, however we can tell you how to limit the harm that such people can do in the workplace : for instace :  make visible your effort, document anything you can, in writing.

Comment: @Walfrat thanks for your advice. I am actually documenting my effort. That's the reason my senior knows I am doing well and that they were infact telling lies.

Comment: Your juniors lack not only ethics, but also experience and, in fact, brains. The lack of ethics is obvious. The lack of experience and brains shows itself in that that they were not able to hide their move, and not even gain a Machiavellian advantage by it. In short, you are lucky they gave it away so easily. I personally would just let the relation go cold and reduce my interaction to the professionally mandated. If you insist on a response, you may ask them:

Comment: Thanks @CaptainEmacs . Now I know what to do. I just have to be wary of them and reduce my interaction to the professionally mandated.

Comment: "I found you black-talking me in front of my boss quite strange when you know it's clearly wrong. Can you explain to me what that was supposed to be?" Look at them silently and wait for response. They are unlikely to answer, though, or respond with irrelevant nonsense or excuses, on which you can nod silently and skeptically. Such a question tells them that you have understood them very well and that they have to be on their guard in the future and shouldn't try this again. I myself most likely would not do it, but some people would like to have that conversation for closure.

Comment: 'Even when they did mistakes, I never shouted.' I don't understand why you feel the need to mention this.

Comment: So waht, people can be fakes. I screamed at one freelancer last friday. Specialist for UI work (Angular)... happens to have 50 large projects under his belt in 4 years (no logic and math obviously) and demosntrated to not know how to open a browser debugger - which is critical, but loved being the senior specialist in charge - except he did nothing. SOme people are lying when they open their mouth. Happens. You get rid of them. Most liers, though, are a little smarter than your idiot junior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trust is a tough one, easy to give - but easy to be used & abused. Hard to regain.

You need to focus on yourself, **make sure that you are honest, trustworthy & hard-working** - keep doing your job. This is what your boss will see. If your job involves helping other then keep doing that - even if you occasionally come unstuck - **your core nature is what your boss will recall if there is a dispute**.

If your co-workers repeatedly unfairly call you out as unhelpful then your boss needs to **address the situation by training - in, say, emotional intelligence - or by disciplinary measures**.

All you can do is make sure that your approach to these juniors & your work is honest & fair - **people grow up or move one**.

Comment: I think this answer was the one I needed to know. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You took this way over-emotionally. Don't get me wrong, I empathize with you. You tried to help them and they threw you under the bus.

The problem is, they are probably both immature. When they perceived that they were being attacked, which I bet they did, they defended themselves by blaming someone else. You. This is very much a "teachable moment" if you want to have that conversation, regarding what resources and support they need from your side. And since they're still juniors, they still need someone to help and guide them like you have been doing.

It was immature from their side, but it wasn't personal. They don't have the power to bring you down (as you saw yourself) and you should't be demoralized by their tantrum. If anything, this is as good a chance to thicken your own skin as it is for them to learn how (not) to behave.

Comment: Remember, he is 4 years into his career. He is still a junior himself.